# Drupal 7: Data not appearing on block's .tpl file after being sent by hook_block_view()

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am taking data from a config form and passing it to a .tpl file to display.

I am using `hook_block_view()` to take the data, put it into an array and send it to the .tpl file.

My code (on .module) is as such:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function message_block_info() {
  return [
    'message_block' => [
      'info' => t('Message'),
      'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_GLOBAL,
    ],
  ];
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function message_theme() {
  return [
    'message_block' => [
      'template' => 'templates/message-block',
      'variables' => [
        'settings' => NULL,
        'attributes' => [],
      ],
    ],
  ];
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function message_block_view($delta = '') {
  if ($delta !== 'message_block') {
    return;
  }

  $config = message_default_settings();

  dpm($config); // <- this shows correct data

  $block['content'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'message_block',
    '#config' => array(
      'message_text' => filter_xss($config['message_text']),
      'message_link' => filter_xss($config['message_link']),
      'message_button_text' => filter_xss($config['message_button_text']),
    ),
  );

  return $block;
}
```

And on the .tpl file:

```
   <?php dpm('test'); //<- This works ?>
   <?php dpm($config); //<- This does not work?>

   <div class="message">
    <?php print $config['message_text']; ?>
    <?php if (!empty($config['message_link']) && !empty($config['alert_button_text'])): ?>
      <a href="<?php print $config['message_link']; ?>" class="button">
        <?php print $config['message_button_text']; ?>
      </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
```

I can place a `dpm('test');` on the .tpl file and it will appear, so I know that the HTML is rendering. Obviously, I've tried clearing cache, too.

Would anyone know if I've missed a step to get this data appearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I was missing the config array initilisation in `hook_theme`:

```
function message_theme() {
  return [
    'message_block' => [
      'template' => 'templates/message-block',
      'variables' => [
        'config' => NULL, //<- Was missing
      ],
    ],
  ];
}
```